# How to filter data for a gridview based upon multiple dropdown boxes's selected values

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an aspx webform written in C#. 
This page has three dropdown boxes. These dropdown boxes load values for Department, Site and Team from the corresponding tables.

Based upon logged in user's permissions an item will be preselected from these three dropdown boxed during page load. On the same page I have a gridview whose data should be filtered based upon the selected values of these three dropdown boxes.

The sql for the gridview's data source should be something like this: `select * from abc where Department = <selecteditem> and Site = <selecteditem> and Team = <selecteditem>`.

I have a button on the page named as *Apply Filter* which takes the selected items and constructs the sql, and the gridview is populated fine. However  I want this filtration to happen automatically during page load event without anyone manually clicking the button after the page load.

I've tried to execute the button click event during the page event, but the filtration doesn't happen. Please let me know the best way to achieve this.

Thanks

Comment: other then page load, are you able to apply filter ? can you post the search code and where in form load you were calling

Comment: Yes, the button click event applies the same filtration, and it works fine.

Comment: can you post your form load and button code

Comment: Currently I don't have the code with me. I could post it little later. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to do like this

```
`protected void DropDownBoxDepartment_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    // Here gives the DataSource for the DataGrid View for the DEPARTMENTSelection   

    }

 protected void DropDownBoxSite_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    // Here gives the DataSource for the DataGrid View for the SITE Selection  (or Department and Site Selection whatever you want)   

    }

      protected void DropDownBoxTeam_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    // Here gives the DataSource for the DataGrid View for the TEAM Selection  (or Department, Site and Team Selection whatever you want)   

    }`
```

Hope this Code Helps You....If I understand your question well.

Answer (score 0):

In the Page_load event do the below:

Get the user name of the user who has logged in currently by:

```
String name = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
```

I hope you could figure out the permissions levels of the user with the user name.

According the permission level set the desired selected index value of your three different drop down list like below (sample)

```
departmentDropDownList.SelectedIndex=1;
```

After setting the desired value for all the three drop down do the Grid `DataBind()`.

**NOTE:** I'm pretty sure you would not require this automated GridView DataBind to happen for all the post back. If that is true then put the above Page_Load code within the below condition so that this automated filtering happens only for the initial page load.

```
if(!IsPostBack){

}
```